# removing duplicates in a list

Tags: python-3.x, list

I am doing a program to remove duplicate words in a list in Python using the `split()` function.

My answer is wrong as it does not removes the duplicate elements.

**romeo.txt:**

```
But soft what light through yonder window breaks
It is the east and Juliet is the sun
Arise fair sun and kill the envious moon
Who is already sick and pale with grief
```

**My code:**

```
fhand=open(romeo.txt)
arr=list()
count=0
for line in fhand:
    words=line.split()
    if words in arr: 
        continue
    else:
        arr=arr+words

arr.sort()
print(arr)
```

Answer (score 1):

1. You need to iterate over each word, **not** each line.
2. Use `append()` to add words to a list.

Example:

```
line="But soft what light through yonder window breaks It is the east and Juliet is the sun Arise fair sun and kill the envious moon Who is already sick and pale with grief"

arr=list()
count=0

words=line.split()
for word in words:
    if word not in arr: 
       arr.append(word)

arr.sort()
print(arr)
```

**Output:**

```
 ['Arise', 'But', 'It', 'Juliet', 'Who', 'already', 'and', 'breaks', 'east', 'envious', 'fair', 'grief', 'is', 'kill', 'light', 'moon', 'pale', 'sick', 'soft', 'sun', 'the', 'through', 'what', 'window', 'with', 'yonder']
```